# Bursting circles

Tags: animation

I am a newbie with Blender and I want to create a very short video where concentric 2D circles burst from the center. As each of these circles move away from the center, its thickness reduces until disappear.
Is there any information source where I can learn this specific need?

Thank you,
Rui

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67440/making-a-radio-wave-transmission-waves

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The related link is interesting because the circles are moving as I want, but what I am looking for is a way to have the thickness of the circles to decrease as they move away from the center.

Comment: That can be easily achieved by animating either the bevel width, bevel object, or curve vertex radius