# Array of 3D circles with same center, and same distance between them, but different radio

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am new at blender, and this is where I am currently:
[image: This is the where I am currently]
I got an initial circle, and applied an Array modifier (with an empty object in the center as object offset), followed by the Solidify modifier so after the scale the shape will keep the thickness. But the distance between the circles is not the same. How can I keep the distance the same?

the shape of each circle should finally look like this:
[image]

Any ideas? THANKS!

Reference image of the project: [image]

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67440/making-a-radio-wave-transmission-waves

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if the intervals along your radii are all the same .. so this is an option:

1. Order up a mesh circle, sides divisible by 4, fan fill.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> Bevel the center vertex to desired diameter
3. Select the radial edges and  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> add edge loops to the desired number.. (right-click out of the operation to leave it without sliding the loops)
4. Select every other face ring ...
5. .. and delete.

[image]

Comment: This is a case where the double mirror would be perfect: delete three quadrants then ~2 more quads from each end, apply x+y mirror, you only have to worry about fiddling with 1/4 as much.

Comment: True.. and I've just noticed  he might want aisles with parallel sides ..

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Create a circle (in this case 32 sides.) Remove 1/2 the vertices and then 1/2 again to give you an arc, i.e. 1/4 of a circle. Add mirror modifier in both x and y to give yourself an full circle again. Add a solidify modifier to desired thickness. Apply both modifiers. Shift+D to duplicate. Scale in the x and y only in Object mode. For the 2nd ring 1.5x, 1.5y and 1z (unless you want the thickness in the Z to increase. Switch to edit mode and select the inner two rings, (alt RMB on one then alt+shift RMB on the 2nd.) Reduce scale to match first ring. Repeat as desired.

Comment: Double-mirroring is a useful technique while modeling sometimes, but it really doesn't seem to be doing anything here for you. Also it's not clear how you're reducing the scale (width) of the rings without reducing their overall size.