# Scale incrementally over time, each instance

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, transforms, instances

I'm been looking for it, but I couldnt figured it out, Do you people know how to make a sequential increase of instances, with or whitout  simulations?

I attach my geo tree, and an example of what I want.

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67440/making-a-radio-wave-transmission-waves/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your question is, that it is not clear, how the animation should look like. Should the scale one after another? or all at the same time?

With this node tree:

[image]

you get this:

[image]

and with this:

[image]

you get that:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for the lack of explanation, sometimes is hard to describe. Its basically the frist example that you give, but without the increase of distance between lines, means, with the same space between the circles. Thanks!