Wave texture not growing

Hey there. My company is building this visualization for telecom. Things are going well. Except I am using this wave texture set to rings on the Z axis. My CEO stopped by and wants it to look more like wifi. He wants the inner rings to start small and get bigger as they go. I am not sure how to do that with the color ramp. I am not really sure how to achieve that effect. I have been trying to play around with it and unfortunately I have gotten mixed results as pictured. I am wondering if there is a way to achieve this gradual growth effect from the inner circle to the outer one. I have even tried different interpolation methods such as constant or cardinal but I don't think that is the right approach.
Thanks for any help.


Would a geometry based solution work, as opposed to a shader based one? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67440/making-a-radio-wave-transmission-waves/

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"
